# How to reduce code when create an cell in apache poi?

Tags: java

I am creating a sheet with apache poi, it have a lot of column and row name so I create a lot of code, I have a lot of code duplicate, How can I can create a function and reuse it for another?

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");



        try  (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("report.xls")) {
            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            row = sheet.createRow(0);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("Shop:");
            cell  = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(4);
            cell = row.createCell(6);
            cell.setCellValue("Export Date:");
            cell = row.createCell(7);
            cell.setCellValue("14.06.2019");

            // -----
            row = sheet.createRow(2);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("Code Supervisor:");
            cell  = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(4);
            cell = row.createCell(6);
            cell.setCellValue("Audit Date:");
            cell = row.createCell(7);
            cell.setCellValue("dd.MM.yyyy");

            //----
            row = sheet.createRow(4);
            cell = row.createCell(6);
            cell.setCellValue("Shop Note:");
            cell = row.createCell(7);
            cell.setCellValue("Note something");

            wb.write(os);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```